# Binding the SelectedItem of a WPF ComboBox to an XML Attribute

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I currently have a DataGrid Column that contains ComboBoxes. The DataGrid is bound to an XML file with the Comboboxes being bound to a subnode (Vehicles). The Values needed are currently showing up in my ComboBox, but the selected value won't set. What am I doing wrong.

Here is my XML Structure

```
<Names>
   <Name isActive="True">
      <Family>Doe</Family>
      <First>John</First>
      <Middle>Deer</Middle>
      <Vehicles>
          <Vehicle isSelected="true">Car1</Vehicle>
          <Vehicle>Car2</Vehicle>
      </Vehicles>
   </Name>
</Names>
```

Here is my XAML

```
 <DataGrid DataContext="{StaticResource CrewInfo}" ItemsSource="{BindingXPath=/Names/Name}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Family Name" Binding="{Binding XPath=Family}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding XPath=First}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Middle Name" Binding="{Binding XPath=Middle}"/>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Vehicles">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox Name="vehicleBox" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Vehicles/Vehicle}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true">
                                    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding XPath=@isSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                </ComboBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Strangely I found the answer on an unrelated thread.

Here is the correct code for theSelectedValue binding.

```
<ComboBox Name="vehicleBox" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Vehicles//*}">
       <ComboBox.SelectedValue>
              <Binding XPath="Vehicles/Vehicle[@isSelected='True']"/>
       </ComboBox.SelectedValue>
</ComboBox>
```